# Preserve character formatting in string variables

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a procedure that takes the selected text and places it into an XE field for use in an index; however, if the selection includes superscript or subscript characters, they are stripped out when I place the variable in the field and the index is created incorrectly.

The form referenced in the code below simply allows the user to type a string, which is then added to the index via another procedure.

```
Sub createAbbreviation()

Dim strFieldTextAbbr As String
Dim rngAbbreviation As Range

If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Then
  Load frmInsertAbbreviation
Else
  Set rngAbbreviation = Selection.FormattedText
  strAbbreviation = Selection.Text
  Load frmInsertAbbreviation
End If

frmInsertAbbreviation.Show
If frmInsertAbbreviation.Tag = "Cancel" Then
  Unload frmInsertAbbreviation
  strAbbreviation = ""
  Exit Sub
End If

strFieldTextAbbr = """" & rngAbbreviation & """ \f Abbreviation \t """ & frmInsertAbbreviation.strDefinition & """"

If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Then
  If Selection.Font.Subscript = True Then
    Selection.Font.Subscript = False
  End If
  ActiveDocument.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldIndexEntry, _
    Text:=strFieldTextAbbr
Else
  Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
  If Selection.Font.Subscript = True Then
    Selection.Font.Subscript = False
  End If
  ActiveDocument.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldIndexEntry, _
    Text:=strFieldTextAbbr
End If

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
  With Selection.Find
    .Text = """"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
  End With

  If Selection.Find.Execute = True Then
    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseRight
    Do Until InStr(1, Selection, Chr(34)) <> 0
      Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Loop
  End If

Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Range.FormattedText = rngAbbreviation

Unload frmInsertAbbreviation
strAbbreviation = ""

End Sub
```

EDIT:

I see that the reason it won't work is because I'm placing the range into a string, effectively negating it's object status. I'm going to continue working on it to see if I can make it work. I feel like I'm on the right track, it's just taking a while to get there. Any help would be appreciated.

It turns out that the issue is that formatted text cannot be placed in the Text argument of the Fields.Add method. What's needed is a way to add the content as formatted text or to reinstate the formatting after the text has been added to the field.

Comment: Understand a Word `Range` as an object comprising characters #x to #y in a document. This object has many properties, prominent among them the `Text` and `Font` which together instruct Word to place the text stored in the `Text` property in the space defined by `Start` and `End` of the range and display it using `Font`. `Font` is another object. Its properties include `Name`, `Size` and `Subscript`, besides `Bold`, `Italic` and spacing. It follows that, if you wish to preserve all properties of a `Range` you can't use a `String` to store them. A string is not an object and stores only text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to pass formatting from place to place in Word is to use the `FormattedText` property of the Range object.

You need to build the XE field in multiple steps: insert the field, bring in the formatted text, append the remaining text as a string.

The sample code uses a simple InputBox to get text from the user; you can work with a UserForm instead, of course.

The example uses two Range objects, one for the selection (that may contain formatting to be retained); the other is for the XE field and its code. Note that `Field.Code` also returns a Range object, which is leveraged here to build the index entry.

```
Sub InsertIndexFieldWithFormatting()
    Dim doc As word.Document
    Dim rngXEcontent As word.Range
    Dim rngXEfield As word.Range
    Dim XEfield As word.Field
    Dim sMoreXEcontent As String

    Set rngXEcontent = Selection.Range
    Set doc = rngXEcontent.Parent
    sMoreXEcontent = InputBox("Content for the index:")
    Set rngXEfield = rngXEcontent.Duplicate

    'Position for the XE field
    rngXEfield.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    rngXEfield.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1

    Set XEfield = doc.Fields.Add(rngXEfield, _
                                 wdFieldIndexEntry, Chr(34), False)
    Set rngXEfield = XEfield.code
    rngXEfield.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    rngXEfield.FormattedText = rngXEcontent.FormattedText
    rngXEfield.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    rngXEfield.InsertAfter " " & sMoreXEcontent & Chr(34) & " "
    'Otherwise the additional text is sub-/superscripted
    rngXEfield.Font.Reset 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll test this and see if it works better than what I came up with.